# ASPNet.CORE Migrate tables from SQLServer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nuget-package

I am starting a new CORE application that uses a SQLServer database, and was using the following command to reverse engineer the current database for a model.

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Data Source=XXX;Initial Catalog=XXX;User ID=XXX;Password=XXX;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -Verbose
```

This leads to the following error that I have not found any resolution for.

```
Startup project 'src\XXXtest' is an ASP.NET Core or .NET Core project for Visual Studio 2015. This version of the Entity Framework Core Package Manager Console Tools doesn't support these types of projects.
```

I have installed packages for NetCoreApp.1.1.1 and Newtonsoft.json. I am using the 4.6.1 framework and using VS2015Community.

Comment: It's an odd error for sure, as it's basically telling you that EF Core doesn't support .NET Core, which is obviously insane. My best guess is that the tooling is out of date with the Core packages your project is using. If you're using the Community Edition, anyways, why don't you go ahead and grab VS 2017? That's got all the latest Core tooling built in rather than having to shoe-horn it into an older VS.

Comment: You can use my GUI tools in SQLite Toolbox (also for SQL Server) twitter.com/ErikEJ/status/834405829889638402